# Ubuntu 12.04 HybridGraphics (ATI and Intel) problem (Acer Aspire 7745g)

Tags: ati, graphics, intel, hybrid-graphics

I have problem with my graphic cards. By default Intel driver had installed. But i cant' install ATI driver.
I want to install both this drivers, or to remove Intel's driver, install ATI's driver. How?

My graphic cards: 
Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Madison [Radeon HD 5000M Series]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First off, you should install Intel drivers:

   apt-get install mesa-utils
2. Then it's time to install ATI drivers, open dash and type jockey

See if Additional Drivers is enabled, if not, try to enable them

There's also a good wiki on switching from discrete and integrated cards here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics